# How to do Q_INTERFACES with PyQt? (Goal: Implement QTextObjectInterface)

Tags: pyqt, pyqt4

I'm trying to implement something similar to Cocoa's NSTokenField with Qt, by placing objects with custom rendering in a QTextEdit.

Qt's text system allows for this by implementing a subclass of QTextObjectInterface to encapsulate the custom drawing code. However, in addition to subclassing, the class also has to make the interface it implements known to the meta-object system. In C++, this is done via the Q_INTERFACES macro in the header:

Q_INTERFACES(QTextObjectInterface)

I've looked at moc's output for a C++ prototype, and what it ends up doing is to generate a qt_metacast() implementation that does something useful for the interface name.

I can't find a way to emulate this using PyQt. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use QtGui.QPyTextObject as the base class of your custom text object. See the richtext/textobject example in the PyQt archive for an example of how to do this.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I need. Still leaves open the question whether there's a generic way to do the Q_INTERFACES thing, I guess :).